# Show other category posts in single.php

Tags: loop, single

On my single.php i want to show the current post and underneath it i want to list all the posts in cat-2. In my loop i tried to query post with cat-2 but it still shows the current post.

```
<?php global $query_string;
$posts = query_posts($query_string.''); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php the_content(); // Dynamic Content ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>    
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
            <h1><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

<hr>
<?php global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&cat=2,&order=ASC'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="wp-post-image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?> " style="width:100%; height:auto;"></a>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Comment: Do not modify main query using query_posts instead create query using WP_Query https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: @VinodDalvit thanks it took me a while but figured it out using wp query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of post of a category can be show using [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like this

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',  //Specifying post type
        'posts_per_page' => 10, //How many posts per page
        'cat' =>'cat2',         //Specifying post category to show posts
        'paged' => $paged       //For pagingation (if required)
        );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>     
    <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>   
<?php 
endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

nstead of using query_posts use wp_query:

```
     <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'your-post-type-name'
                      'cat'=>4,
                      'order'=>'ASC'
                     );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($args); // required
            // The Loop
        if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo '<h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo "no posts found";
        }
        ?>
```